# How to structure this SELECT query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In MS SQL Server, using the following data, how do I find empIds that have dept 10 complete (=1) and no entry for dept 11?

```
deptId    empId   complete
10         3         1
11         3         0
10         4         1
10         5         1
11         5         0
12         5         1
10         6         1
10         7         1
11         7         0
```

This should return empIds 4 and 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Response:

```
select distinct empId
from employees e
where e.deptId= 10 and complete = 1
and e.emId not in
  (select s_e.empId
   from employees s_e 
   where s_e.deptId = 11
   )
```

the query is the list of employees that have dept 10 complete (=1)

the subquery is the list of employees that has entry for dept11.

With CTE:

```
WITH employees_excluded_CTE (idEmp)
AS
(
   select s_e.empId
       from employees s_e 
       where s_e.deptId = 11
)
 select distinct empId
    from employees e
    where e.deptId= 10 and complete = 1
    and e.emId not in
      (select s_e.empId
       from employees_excluded_CTE
       );
GO
```

Comment: Thanks.  I wasn't sure how the subquery should fit in.

Comment: @4thSpace Your answer rate is starting to reach poverty level. You should mark this as answered if it is such.

Comment: @Matthew Cox, I really have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: @danihp, do you know how this would change if you still want e.deptId= 10 and complete = 1 and those that don't have a deptId=10 entry instead of 11.

Comment: @4thSpace What I am saying is that your Answer Rate is at 57% which is less than satisfactory. People here are less likely to answer your questions if they suspect that you won't take the time to mark a question as answered and give rep where rep is due.

Comment: @Matthew Cox: When I first started using stackoverflow, I didn't accept answers as much.  But now I always do.  The problem is that I cannot easily track down older unanswered questions.

Comment: Actually, looks like that has changed.  I can just click questions in my profile and all of those with white answers are unanswered.  Notice I went from 57% to 60%.  I'll be working on those.

Comment: To get only deptid=10 change where clause on subquery: where dptid=10 and complete <> 1.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever possible, in cases such as this I try to write logic that only needs to parse the data once.

I can see a few ways of doing that without having to use joins or sub-queries, here are a couple.  The exact form depends on the nature of your data (duplicates, etc) and/or the indexes you have, or can create.

Most Generic (All in `HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN THEN) = 0`)

```
SELECT
  empID
FROM
  yourTable
WHERE
  deptId IN (10,11)  -- The only two that matter to your logic
GROUP BY
  empID
HAVING
  MAX(CASE WHEN deptId = 11                  THEN 1
           WHEN deptId = 10 AND complete = 0 THEN 1
                                             ELSE 0
      END) = 0
```

More specified, less generalisable:

```
SELECT
  empID
FROM
  yourTable
WHERE
  (deptId = 10 AND completed = 1)
  OR
  (deptId = 11)
GROUP BY
  empID
HAVING
  MAX(deptId) = 10
```

Comment: @danihp - Both of these code examples deal with that condition.  In the first, the presence of any such entry sends the `MAX(CASE WHEN THEN)` to 1, and thus fails the `= 0` check.  In the latter the `MAX(deptId)` goes to 11 and fails the `= 10` check.  Please test this should you feel that it fails on logical criteria.